# Entity Framework scalar function mapping

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql, entity-framework-4, user-defined-functions

I have a scalar function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CheckLocation]
(
    @locationId Int
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    //code
END
```

I want to use it in Entity Framework context.

I have added this in the SSDL of the EDMX file:

```xml
<Function Name="CheckLocation" ReturnType="bit" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo" >
    <Parameter Name="locationId" Type="int" Mode="In" />
</Function>
```

I have also created a partial class with a method decorated with `EdmFunctionAttribute`:

```cs
public partial class MainModelContainer
{
    [EdmFunction("MainModel.Store", "CheckLocation")]
    public bool CheckLocation(int locationId)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls not supported");
    }
}
```

I try to use this function like this:

```
Context.CheckLocation(locationId);
```

And I get `NotSupportedException("Direct calls not supported")`.

It works within the `Select` method, but it does not suit me.

How can I call this function without using the `Select` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to access it as a select

```
var students = context.Locations
    .Select ( new  {  location= CheckLocation(locationId)}):
```

Comment: Is this possible to use UDFs not within Select in the EF 4.5?

Comment: you should be able to use it in a .Where clause as well